# Using CHARTJS with a JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, charts, chart.js

I'm having some issues with the following code :

```
 function processData(csv)
 {
    var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var tarr = [];

    for (var i=1; i<11; i++) 
    {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(';');
        if (i==1)
        {
            tarr = [{ commande: data[0], periode: data[1], jours: data[2] }];  
        }

        tarr = tarr.concat([{ commande: data[0], periode: data[1], jours: data[2] }]);
    }   

    $('#chartContainer').dxChart('option', 'dataSource', tarr);
 }
```

As you may have understood, I'm just trying to "refresh" a CHARTJS chartContainer with new values that I would be reading from a CSV file. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work when I use a simple javascript Array as a Datasource. Using "concat" is the best way, though, as "push" is just a mess in this case, and I didn't manage to generate anything.

I'd like to read a CSV file and generate a js Array like this :

```
var dataSource = [
    { commande: "Commande 001", periode: "2014/01", jours: 12.0 },
    { commande: "Commande 002", periode: "2014/01", jours: 35.0 },

    { commande: "Commande 001", periode: "2014/02", jours: 24.0 },
    { commande: "Commande 002", periode: "2014/02", jours: 68.0 },

    { commande: "Commande 001", periode: "2014/03", jours: 91.0 },
    { commande: "Commande 002", periode: "2014/03", jours: 76.0 },

    { commande: "Commande 001", periode: "2014/04", jours: 53.0 },
    { commande: "Commande 002", periode: "2014/04", jours: 48.0 },

    { commande: "Commande 001", periode: "2014/05", jours: 31.0 },
    { commande: "Commande 002", periode: "2014/05", jours: 10.0 },

    { commande: "Commande 001", periode: "2014/06", jours: 90.0 },
    { commande: "Commande 002", periode: "2014/06", jours: 10.0 },

    { commande: "Total", periode: "2014/01", jours: 47.0 },
    { commande: "Total", periode: "2014/02", jours: 92.0},
    { commande: "Total", periode: "2014/03", jours: 167.0 },
    { commande: "Total", periode: "2014/04", jours: 101.0 },
    { commande: "Total", periode: "2014/05", jours: 41.0 },
    { commande: "Total", periode: "2014/06", jours: 100.0 },                             
];
```

This is the code I'm using to make my first chart (without reading anything), and it seems to work just fine.

Using the tarr Array to refresh this chart, reading a CSV file is my problem.

Y Axis is absolutely out of control ! (multiple values, multiple 0, X Axis damaged, not the chart itself though, as I put random values in the CSV file).

My (simple) CSV :

```
commande,periode,jours
Commande 001;2014/01;0.0
Commande 002;2014/01;86.0
Commande 001;2014/02;83.0
Commande 002;2014/02;78.0
Commande 001;2014/03;81.0
Commande 002;2014/03;76.0                  
Commande 001;2014/04;83.0
Commande 002;2014/04;38.0
Commande 001;2014/05;81.0
Commande 002;2014/05;0.0
Commande 001;2014/06;100.0
Commande 002;2014/06;0.0                 
Total;2014/01;72.0
Total;2014/02;61.0
Total;2014/03;57.0
Total;2014/04;11.0
Total;2014/05;81.0
Total;2014/06;100.0
```

I don't get it. Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first check your regexp `csv.split(/\r\n|\n/)` whether it returns an array of lines. IF it is correct, you should rewrite your method so:

```
function processData(csv)
{
    var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var tarr = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) 
    {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(';');
        tarr.push({ commande: data[0], periode: data[1], jours: parseFloat(data[2]) });
    }

    $('#chartContainer').dxChart('option', 'dataSource', tarr);
}
```

I moved `var data` inside the loo; replaced `concat` by `push` ; and replaced the number 11 by the length of the array.

Proof that it works on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WL22j/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Var data inside the loop was a copy/paste mistake, it used to be inside the loop while I was doing my tests (same thing for 11). I edited. I tried to push instead of concat : it doesn't work. Basically, using push produces no chart at all while concat is OK, except for the Y axis which has dumb values : (11 / 57 / 61 / 62 / 0 / 0 / etc.) It's supposed to be a 100% scale !

Comment: In my example push will create the same array as concat, you just used it wrong. Your Y axis looks bad because it takes values from some incorrect property. Specify argumentField and valueField like in example: http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Tutorial/Configure_Charts#Provide_Data

Comment: My argumentField and valueField are OK. It's not about creating a new chart (even though...), just about refreshing an existing one. I already have : $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    commonSeriesSettings: {
        argumentField: "periode",
        valueField: "jours" //etc.} It works just fine.

Comment: It's filled with a var dataSource just like the one mentioned in my original post, not a read one.

Comment: Anyways, I'm sorry to say that I can't push (I just tried YOUR code, it produces nothing), while concat seems ok but bad axis.

Comment: @Ouarflol My code works, don't even tell otherwise because it's a lie. I even created a simple chart on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WL22j/ where I copied exactly my function without changes. And it displays a chart as it should. I will add the jsfiddle link and a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: And in order to fix the axis use `jours: parseFloat(data[2])` Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/WL22j/1/